# Reading password from console in Scala

Tags: scala, input

In a Scala program I need to read from the standard input a password string (with echoing disabled). I tried with:

```
java.io.Console.readPassword
```

But for some reason I cannot invoke any methods in the `java.io.Console` object from Scala (?).

Which is the "standard" way to read a string (with echoing disabled) from the standard input in Scala ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you want to read the password from the console prompt, so you will need to create a `Console` instance from the `System` (`Console` is not a singleton).

```
scala> val standardIn = System.console()
standardIn: java.io.Console = java.io.Console@69d1964d

scala> val password = standardIn.readPassword()
```

Note that no `import` is necessary because of Scala's type inference and the fact that `System` is already in scope by default.

Consult the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) for `java.io.Console` for more info.

*EDIT*: In a compiled Scala program:

```
object ReadPassword {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val standardIn = System.console()
    println("standardIn object: " + standardIn)

    print("Password> ")
    val pw = standardIn.readPassword()

    print("Password: ")
    pw.foreach(print) // For demonstration purposes
    println()
  }
}
```

Compiling/running:

```
$ scalac ReadPassword.scala
$ scala ReadPassword
standardIn object: java.io.Console@311671b2
Password> 
Password: hello world
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I can get an instance of the Console in the REPL tool, as in your code. However, if I try to do the same in a Scala program (or in a Scala worksheet), standardIn gets a null value. No idea why.

Comment: `standardIn` is the console object, the `getPassword` method will return a `char[]` of the password entered. I've added an example of a sample program I wrote and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: When I do this in a unit test (haven't tried it elsewhere) the prompt doesn't seem to wait for me, the test just continues on and eventually throws an NPE, since of course `pw` is `null`.

Comment: Why val password = standardIn.readPassword() is only taking a single character ?

Comment: @adelbertc `print("Password> ")` + `standardIn.readPassword()` => `standardIn.readPassword("Password> ")`